# How to request access token with scope in azure ad (customer API)

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a .net core API which deploy on the azure app service,it is register as a azure ad application.
I also add a API scope in expose an API,which is

```
https://domain.name/Resource.GetStatus
```

I also register another application and give the  delegate API permission.
Now I want to request a access token with scope in it in postman,but when I put the value to the scope
such error will happen

```
{
    "error": "invalid_scope",
    "error_description": "AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://aa-cdapublic-dev.azurewebsites.net/Resource.GetStatus is not valid.\r\nTrace ID: 8256ed8d-65e8-4ad4-865b-0a6fbf473500\r\nCorrelation ID: 65cef3a9-8aa1-4103-8c91-ac2007e27bc0\r\nTimestamp: 2020-04-21 03:47:52Z",
    "error_codes": [
        70011
    ],
    "timestamp": "2020-04-21 03:47:52Z",
    "trace_id": "8256ed8d-65e8-4ad4-865b-0a6fbf473500",
    "correlation_id": "65cef3a9-8aa1-4103-8c91-ac2007e27bc0"
}
```

my postman request as belows:

```
method :post
URl:https://login.microsoftonline.com/devglobal.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
clientid:******
clientsecret:******
scope:https://domain.name/Resource.GetStatus
```

I haven't try it in a SPA page with implicit flow yet,first of all I want to check it whether my settings is correct or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `client_credentials` as "grant_type", you need to set `https://domain.name/.default` instead of `https://domain.name/Resource.GetStatus` as scope (otherwise it will show the error message as you mentioned in question). By the way, if you use `client_credentials`, you can't get the delegate permission. So you should use "implicit flow". I test it in my side with "implicit flow", it can get `Resource.GetStatus` from the access token success.

**Update:**

[image]

[image]

decode the access token:
[image]

Comment: hmm,does it also means if we use a application authentication we can not get the scope from the claims?For the implicit flow,do you test it in tools such as post man or in the SPA page? Can you please send me as a reference?  I checked it in my side but failed

Comment: Hi @KevinYANG I test implicit flow by using tool "Talend API Tester", please check the screenshots in the "Update" in my answer.

Comment: I have a question here,regarding to the scopes who can consent,If I sign in and consent the scope,does it means that these scope will belong to my account even I already delete the scope? I'm using scopes with "https://domainname/Resource.GetStatus" to do a post or get request but in the accesstoken I got,the scp is "Resource.Create Resource.GetStatus" ,I was confused about that where it is comes

Comment: @KevinYANG When you sign in and get the access token, the access token will expire in 1 hour(the default expire time is 1 hour). During 1 hour, your account has these scopes but if you re-sign in or over 1 hour, it will not has the scopes.

Comment: Got two point:1 the scope with these scope"Resource.Create Resource.GetStatus" will appear in every request token since I first consent it (in implicit flow I use)2  it seems that If I add a new scope and add it in my request(https://domainname/testscope),this request will failed and error "consent_required and The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID...." happen,but I can not get where to consent.How did you add that new permission in your app？

Comment: @KevinYANG Just grant the admin consent in this [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtYxj.png).

Comment: Thanks for your information,I saw the settings.It looks like an administrative authority is needed here

Comment: @KevinYANG If the solution helps your problem, could you please mark it as "accepted", thanks~